# Communicate with process in C#

Tags: c#, process

I need to communicate with external executable (ampl.exe) using standard input and standard output. This exe make calculations during some minutes with some display in the console. It has a prompt so I can succesively launch calculations by using its standard input as soon as a calculation is finished.

The external exe is launched as :

```
var myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ampl.exe");
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
myProcess.Start();
```

I communicate with it by using myProcess.StandardInput and myProcess.StandardOutput (synchronous way).

I use standard input to launch the calcul, for example :

```
myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("solve;");
```

I want to wait the end of the solve statement, get results in files, prepare new calculation input files and then launching a second solve.

My problem is that I do now know when the first calculation is finished, that is when the exe is waiting for new command in its standard input.
The only way I found is to add a specific display command and wait for getting it it its standard output :

```
    myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("solve;");
    myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("print 'calculDone';");
    string output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    while (!output.Contains("calculDone"))
    {
        output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine();
    }
```

Is there another way avoiding to use this display command to do this ?

Edit : following advices, I tried the asynchronous way. But I still need to print 'CalculDone' to know when the solve statement ended. I do not get the prompt of ampl.exe (which is 'ampl : ') in the standard output of the process.

```
AutoResetEvent eventEnd = new AutoResetEvent(false);

var myProcess = new Process();
myProcess.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("ampl.exe");
myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
myProcess.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Data == "commandDone")
    {
        eventEnd.Set();
    }
    else if (e.Data != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ampl: {0}", e.Data);
    }
};

myProcess.Start();
myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("solve;");
myProcess.StandardInput.WriteLine("print 'commandDone';");

eventEnd.WaitOne();
```

Comment: Many programs like this output a prompt (e.g. `>> `), if yours does you can watch for that instead of sending an extra print command.

Comment: When you get tired of trying to get your app to interactively communicate with an `exe`, you should then try a `dll` (class library), which is designed specifically for this sort of thing. Unless of course you have no control over the `exe` that you are working with.

Comment: @NightOwl888 : there is no dll for this exe so I have no choice.

Comment: @BenVoigt : the prompt is "myExe : " but even if it appears on screen when I launch manually the exe, it does not appear in the standart output in C#

Comment: The program you start will buffer its output, nothing shows up until either the buffer is full, the program explicitly flushes the buffer or it completes and closes stdout.  Nothing you can do about that if you don't have the source code for the program.

Comment: @HansPassant: Generally I/O libraries default to automatically flushing output before reading input.  Otherwise interactive users would face the same problem that the parent process does here.  On *nix systems, there's an additional factor in play of whether stdin and stdout are bound to pipes or ttys, but usage of C# and frequent mention of "EXE" suggests that this most likely is not a *nix system.

Comment: Yes I am using Windows 10 (.NET 4.0).

Answer (score 1):

The best option would be to use the `Processs.OutputDataReceived` event instead of a tight while loop. It’s like the event async pattern, you launch an asynchronous task and wait for an event callback telling you it’s done. The continuation of the asynchronous task would go in the event handler. Remember to unsubscribe the event handler the first time it goes off, otherwise it will be firing when you don’t want it to.

Another option I have never tried is `Process.WaitForInputIdle()` method, but I’m not sure if this will work in your particular case. If it does you wouldn’t need to write anything to the input stream.

Comment: I don't see how it helps.
I tried to use asynchronous read of standard output but it does not change anything : I still need to print 'calculDone' to know that the calcul is finished and the exe waiting for new input

Comment: @NicoGDF Evidently, but you are not blocking with a loop waiting for an input. If your application has a UI your current code will freeze it, an event approach won't. And what's is wrong in writing to the input stream? Does it make your process crash? And you can try `WaitFroInputIdle`, that will block although you can always run it asynchronously via `Task`. Does that work?

Comment: There is no graphic interface for the exe so WaitForInputIdle crashes. My application is a console application.

Comment: @NicoGDF  Subscribing the `Processs.OutputDataReceived` event is the correct path. When the process you are monitoring terminates its processing phase, it outputs "something" (since you say it doesn't terminate). It can be a message that the calculation is finished, or a prompt. The event will fire each time the process writes something in stdout (redirected). You can take action when you receive what you are expecting. You can also use its in-process progress outputs, if any, to update your console.

Comment: @Jimi I dit it but I do not get the prompt with events when using OutputDataReceived

Comment: @NicoGDF  You have set `myProcess.EnableRaisingEvents = true;` and subscribed (`myProcess.OutputDataReceived += (object source, DataReceivedEventArgs e) => { "Code Here"  };`) the event. Right?

Comment: @Jimi Yes it is what I did. And just after the `Start()`, I call `BeginOutputReadLine()`. However I notice a strange thing : the event is raised two times with e.Data as empty string. Maybe it indicates the start and the end of the execution of command. I need more testing.

Comment: @NicoGDF Be sure you're not mixing asynchronous and synchronous (e.g. `.StandardOutput.ReadLine()`) methods and that there are no other loops, like the one you're showing in your question.

Comment: @Jimi Yes I am sure because an exception is thrown if I call myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine() after myProcess.BeginOutputReadLine()

Comment: @NicoGDF Yes, but you could use `StandardError.ReadLine()` without exceptions. Maybe update your question with the code you have so far, if you still have problems. Mind that you're the only one that can test the output of that process (and also that this is InBetween's answer).

Comment: @Jimi I just dit it ;)

Comment: @NicoGDF  Well, good job. I'm glad you succeeded. Remember to accept the answer.

Comment: @Jimi in fact I have not really solved my issue. The problem is the same between synchronous and asynchronous : I cannot detect the end of solve statement (for example by getting the prompt) and I am forced to add "print 'commandDone'" for this. But I am now thinking that there is no other way.